# jQuery Hide an anchor if it has a specific name

Tags: jquery

I have a nav list, That is built in PyroCMS and it looks like its going to be a bit tricky to exclude the nav item from the list. So I am going to look at doing with jQuery instead.

What I would like to do is if the **a** tag has the text of "General Application" or "Apply Now" is hide it from the current view.

I've had a quick look at doing this, But to no avail.

My current code is pretty simple at the moment.

```
    var link = $('.children a').text();

if(link == 'General Application')
{
    link.hide();
}
```

The current list looks like this :

General Application

Sous Chef

Chef De Partie

Comment: `$('a:contains(General Application)').hide()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('.children a:contains(General Application)').hide();
```

But the above may not always consistent if there is another anchor which might contain the searched text and some additional text like 'General Application - 1' - in this case the above one will hide both the elements.

So try a custom [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('.children a').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'General Application'
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
$('.children a:contains("General Application")').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$('.children').find('a:contains(General Application), a:contains(Sous Chef), a:contains(Chef De Partie)').hide();
```

(You can add more selectors by separating them with a comma)